# How to create linear gradient using SCSS variables?

Tags: html, css, sass, background-color

I am trying to create a linear gradient using scss variables. Here is what I have tried.

```
$colour__social--ig:  linear-gradient(#fdc468 to #ee867c to #df4996);
```

and then I am assigning the colour to `.wrapper` class.

```
background-color: $colour__social--ig;
```

BUT I have no idea why this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gradient doesn't work as a `background-color`. Use the `background` property instead.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to give a direction for the gradient, like:

```
$colour__social--ig:  linear-gradient(to left, $startColor, $endColor);
```